# $ \lim_{s\to +\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx- \frac{\pi}{2}f(0)s-\frac{f'(0)}{2}\ln{s}\right)$

Tags: analysis, integration

Suppose:
$f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)\in C^2[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/2+\dotsb+1/n-\ln{n})$.

Prove:$$  \lim_{s\to +\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx- \frac{\pi}{2}f(0)s-\frac{f'(0)}{2}\ln{s}\right)= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x}{2\sin^2x}\,dx+\frac{f'(0)}{2}(1+\ln2+\gamma)  .    
$$

I can only prove that$$\lim_{s\to +\infty}\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0).$$

I think we can calculate the asymptotic expansion of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx$ (as $s \to +\infty$), but it is hard for me.

Comment: Welcome to MO!  Editorialising about the difficulty of the problem usually doesn't belong, especially in the title, so I have removed it.

Comment: What is the origin of this question, if I may ask?

Comment: I learn mathematics by watching a math video dedicated to a math creator.He always .He always explains some particularly difficult competition questions in our country.For this question,he only proves  that$$\lim_{s\to +\infty}\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0).$$,and he left the question I mentioned as a reflection question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}$Let
\begin{equation*}
    L(s):=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}\,f(x)\,dx- \frac\pi2f(0)s
    -\frac{f'(0)}2\ln s, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    R:=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x}{2\sin^2x}\,dx+\frac{f'(0)}2\,(1+\ln2+\ga). 
\end{equation*}
We have to show that
\begin{equation*}
    L(s)\overset{\text{(?)}}\to R \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
(as $s\to\infty$).
Let
\begin{equation*}
    g(x):=f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x, 
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    L(s)=I_1(s)+f(0)(I_2(s)-\pi s/2)+f'(0)(I_3(s)-\tfrac12\,\ln s),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    R=\tfrac12\,J_1+f'(0)J_3,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    I_1(s):=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}\,g(x)\,dx, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    I_2(s):=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}\,dx, \quad 
    I_3(s):=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}\,x\,dx, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    J_1:=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{g(x)\,dx}{\sin^2x},\quad
    J_3:=\frac{1+\ln2+\ga}2.
\end{equation*}

So, it is enough to show that
\begin{equation*}
    I_1(s)\overset{\text{(?)}}\to \tfrac12\,J_1, \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    I_2(s)-\pi s/2\overset{\text{(?)}}\to 0, \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    I_3(s)-\tfrac12\,\ln s\overset{\text{(?)}}\to J_3. \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}

Since $f\in C^2[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac1{\sin^2x}\,|g(x)|\,dx<\infty$. Also, $\sin^2(sx)=\frac12\,(1-\cos2sx)$. So, \eqref{20} follows by the Riemann--Lebesgue lemma (RL).

To prove  \eqref{30} and  \eqref{40}, the key is to consider
\begin{equation*}
    h(x):=\frac1{\sin^2 x}-\frac1{x^2}
\end{equation*}
for $x\in(0,\pi/2]$. Indeed, note that $\int_0^{\pi/2}|h|<\infty$.

So, again by RL,
\begin{align*}
    I_2(s)&=\int_0^{\pi/2} h(x)\sin^2(sx)\,dx \\ 
&   +\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{x^2}\,dx - \int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{x^2}\,dx \\ 
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2} h(x)\,dx+o(1) \\ 
&   +\frac{\pi s}2 -\frac12 \int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac1{x^2}\,dx+o(1) \\ 
&=\frac{\pi s}2+o(1),
\end{align*}
so that \eqref{30} is proved as well.

Finally,
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    I_3(s)&=\int_0^{\pi/2} h(x)x\sin^2(sx)\,dx +\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{x}\,dx \\ 
    &=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2} h(x)x\,dx +o(1)
    +\frac12\, (-\text{Ci}(\pi s)+\ln s+\ga +\ln\pi) \\  
        &=\frac12\,(1+\ln2-\ln\pi) 
    +\frac12\, (\ln s+\ga +\ln\pi)+o(1),  
\end{aligned}
\tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation*}
where $\text{Ci}(\pi s):=-\int_{\pi s}^\infty\frac{dt}t\,\cos t$, the value of the [cosine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) at $\pi s$; for the penultimate equality in \eqref{50}, use again the identity $\sin^2(sx)=\frac12\,(1-\cos2sx)$, RL, and the latter expression in the definition of $\text{Ci}$ in that Wikipedia article, and for the last equality in \eqref{50} use the first expression in the definition of $\text{Ci}$ in the Wikipedia article.
So, \eqref{40} is proved, too. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thanks for your solution!May I ask how do you calculate $I_3(s)$?

Comment: Can you add more details about $I_3(s)$?Thanks!

Comment: @MathNoob : I have added details there.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Ok,I see,Thank you for your precise answer！

Comment: @MathNoob : You are welcome. The first letter in my first name is the upper case of i, and it's pronounced as Yosef. Unfortunately, in what seems to be most commonly used fonts, the lower-case ell and the upper case of i are almost indistinguishable.

Comment: I'm sorry for writing your name incorrectly.My English level is very poor.And I treat“I”as“L” casually.

Comment: @MathNoob : No reason to be sorry -- it's the font's "fault"! :-)

Comment: @MathNoob : Sorry, I don't engage in such chats.

Comment: :I just try the function of“discussion”of this forum.Sorry to disturb you.Are you a professor at the Michigan technology university?I am fortunate that a professor has answered my doubts. I am just a low-level undergraduate student in mathematic

Comment: @MathNoob : Welcome to MathOverflow! There are a great many professors on this forum.

Comment: @ losif Pinelis :Thank you for your warm welcome！